# Symfony 6: Command "make:repository" is not defined

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, php-8

I did a fresh installation.

- OS: Ubuntu Linux 22.04.1
- Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-58-generic on x86_64
- PHP 8.1.2
- Symfony 6.2.6 (env: dev, debug: true)
- Doctrine: 2.14.1

This is what I did to create an empty project with Symfony:

```
cd /var/www/html
symfony new <project>
cd <project>
composer req --dev symfony/profiler-pack
composer req maker doctrine twig asset
```

Server (*symfony server:start*) is working fine. Profiler also.

But maker does not know about repositories.

```
php bin/console make:repository
```

> [critical] Error thrown while running command "'make:repository'".
> Message: "Command "make:repository" is not defined.

What now?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache ?

Comment: You also need to install the symfony/maker-bundle to get the make commands.  Even after doinhg so you might be slightly disappointed as there is no `make:repository` command.   `make:entity` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App
```

It generates the repository classes.

God knows why.

Comment: I'm not actually a god though I am often mistaken for one.   There is no make:repository command so that explains your original error.  The --regenerate basically recreates all the getter/setter nonsense.  Specifying the App namespace to regenerate all entities is a bit surprising.  In general the only real way to understand the maker stuff is to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

The repository is created only after the entity is created, namely, you must initially create the entity through the `bin/console make:entity` command, and only then will you have the repository created